# How to split numeric column(fieldname) into 2 columns with sql (access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a numeric column (Fieldname) which has numerical values (year and month ,no day) without seperator.

It looks like this:

```
Fieldname
201701
201612
201704
201010
```

How do I split this fieldname into 2 columns with SQL Access and make it look like this

```
Fieldname Second_fieldname 
2017      01
2016      12
2017      04
2010      10
```

Thanks

Comment: _Columns_, not colons/fields.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a numerical column, you can calculate the year and month parts:

```
year = YearMonth \ 100
month = YearMonth MOD 100
```

The `\` operator performs an integer division, discarding any remainder. The `MOD` operator returns just that remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Format*:

```
YearMonth = Format("201802", "@@@@ @@")
```

or:

```
YearMonth = Format(201802, "0000 00")
```